# PLS-00302: component 'M' must be declared in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to convert table type data into single variable with ',' separated
also I dont know what column used in table type. please let us know how to achieve it without passing column name, output must be string type.

```
DECLARE
    TEST_TAB ADT.TEST_TABB2 := ADT.TEST_TABB2(adt.test_obj(2,
    'dsd'),
    adt.test_obj(3,
    'agg'));

l_name clob := '';

CURSOR c IS
SELECT
    ATTR_NAME
FROM
    ALL_TYPE_ATTRS
WHERE
    OWNER = 'ADT'
    AND TYPE_NAME = (
    SELECT
        REFERENCED_NAME
    FROM
        DBA_DEPENDENCIES
    WHERE
        REFERENCED_OWNER = 'ADT'
        AND NAME = 'TEST_TABB2'
        AND REFERENCED_TYPE = 'TYPE');

t nvarchar2(500) := '';

BEGIN

FOR i IN TEST_TAB.FIRST .. TEST_TAB.LAST
 LOOP
 
 l_name := l_name || '(';

FOR cur IN c LOOP
 
 t := cur.ATTR_NAME;

dbms_output.put_line(t);

l_name := l_name || ' ' || t ;

l_name := l_name || ', ' || TEST_TAB(i).t;
END LOOP;

l_name := l_name || ')' ;
END LOOP;

dbms_output.put_line(l_name);
END;
```

Comment: `m` isn't an attribute of your object type. It would help if you explained - in the question, not as comments - what you are actually trying to do. It appears you're trying to access the actual named attributes dynamically using the *value* of `m` - but that won't work. If you explain more you might get some suggestions on how to achieve whatever you actually need to do.

Comment: I need table type column name dynamically without hardcoding. but in oracle 11g it is not working.

Comment: You may also serialize object type into an XML document and then use XMLTable or XSLT to convert it to name/value pair. See  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f2f398d0a2b3852d8cb4ee897b88d741

Answer (score 1):

You could use dynamic SQL, concatenating in the attribute name, and passing the object as a bind variable:

```
...
BEGIN
  FOR i IN TEST_TAB.FIRST .. TEST_TAB.last LOOP
    FOR cur IN c LOOP
      m := '.' || cur.ATTR_NAME;
      execute immediate 'select :o' || m || ' from dual'
      into t
      using test_tab(i);
      dbms_output.put_line(t);
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

or

```
...
BEGIN
  FOR i IN TEST_TAB.FIRST .. TEST_TAB.last LOOP
    FOR cur IN c LOOP
      execute immediate 'select :o.' || cur.ATTR_NAME || ' from dual'
      into t
      using test_tab(i);
      dbms_output.put_line(t);
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

which both produce output;

```
2
John
3
Devid
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=aef52a8589d9b6956fdeb05888d94461)

The first block above doesn't work in the unpatched version of 11gR2 available in db<>fiddle, but I'm not quite sure why, or whether it would work in a later, patched, version. The second block [does work](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=97788f714542aafcbd267e83cd02a706) though.